# How to make rolls airier and crustier?

Tags: baking, bread

I'm working on a bread roll recipe that's 66% water (it's wet, but I'm still able to shape into rolls), 4% powdered skim milk, 1.8% ADY, 1.6% salt, 10% sugar, and 8% shortening. I divide the rolls into 30 grams per roll. I spray the buns and put in extra steam in the oven when I bake them. I also start the first couple of minutes of baking at the highest oven temperature, then drop it to about ~300F/150C for a total baking time of about 15 minutes.

It's a very basic dough recipe. When baked, the rolls come out slightly sweet, very soft, and moist. It's a decent bread roll.

However, I would like the crumb to be a bit airier and slightly drier. And I want the crust to be slightly thicker and flakier (but not as thick and flaky as a French baguette).

What adjustments can I make to my formula to achieve the crumb and crust texture that I am looking for? I'm thinking that less sugar and possibly less shortening might help? Should I drop my shortening to 3% (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bread#Fats_or_shortenings)? Would those changes help me?

Also, besides changing my formula, is there anything else I can do to help achieve my goals?

Comment: What kind of flour are you using? What’s your method? And if you have some on hand, we’d love a photo or two...?

Comment: Bread flour. How does method affect crumb and crust?

Comment: that’s a question in itself ;-) The time when you add the salt and/or fat, the way of kneading (or not kneading), cold vs. warm rise, especially with 8% fat, any kind of pre-fermentation or autolyse step... will all have an influence, some more, some less.

Comment: Flour and water is combined gently, then left to rest for about 30 mins (autolyse). Milk and yeast added, then kneaded by machine until fully incorporated. Salt added and added until good gluten development. Sugar added and kneaded by machine until dough passes window pane. Shortening added last and kneaded by machine until fully incorporated.